# Spring auto convert LocalDate from request

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible that Spring (4.3) automatically converts my custom Date into a LocalDate format?

I have a simple request method (I don't know how it is really called): `ResponseEntity<?> placeOrder(@RequestBody PlaceOrderForm form);`

And this is my PlaceOrderForm:

```
public class PlaceOrderForm {
    private LocalDate deliveryDate;

    public LocalDate getDeliveryDate() {
        return deliveryDate;
    }

    public void setDeliveryDate(LocalDate deliveryDate) {
        this.deliveryDate = deliveryDate;
    }
}
```

I read about a custom converter ... I created one:

```
@Component
public class StringToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate convert(String source) {
        String format = messageSource.getMessage("text.store.dateformat", null, i18nService.getCurrentLocale());
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);

        return LocalDate.parse(source, formatter);
    }
}
```

Also I read that I need to tell the ConversionService, that I have a new Converter:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list merge="true">
            <bean id="stringToLocalDateConverter" class="de.test.converter.StringToLocalDateConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But all that is not helping and I get the following error:
`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of java.time.LocalDate (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('10.10.2019'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of java.time.LocalDate (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('10.10.2019')`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add a configuration class that adds the JavaTime module to jackson:

```
@Configuration
public class SampleApplication {

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @PostConstruct
  public void createObjectMapper() {
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working. I get the same error message like before

Answer (score 0):

Use annotation in class PlaceOrderForm as bellow and as you use `@RequestBody PlaceOrderForm form` add a default constructor

```
    public class PlaceOrderForm {
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
        private LocalDate deliveryDate;

       public PlaceOrderForm(){}
```

add the following method in `@controller` class

```
 @InitBinder
public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Comment: Okay I found a way to implement the pattern through a propertie, but it's not working. I get the same error message like before